# ssh-keygen command not found when setting up Git on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, git

I'm following [the steps here](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/). I'm on step **3** of **Set Up SSH Keys**.

When I type in:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemailhere"`

I get the response:

> ssh-keygen: command not found

What is this supposed to mean?  I'm using the portable version of Git, I've got open `bash.exe` from inside the bin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it would appear that you don't have  ssh installed on your computer.  you will need an ssh client, since it appears you on using windows you can use http://cygwin.com/  and it will come with one, I don't know about a portable version of ssh, though..

Comment: The msysGit package comes with OpenSSH.

Answer (score 13):

The tutorial on GitHub is wrong. The correct one is `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C`

I also had this problem.

Comment: I think it is ssh-keygen.exe

Comment: It worked like charm !

Comment: mine goes with ssh-keygen -t rsa         (no -C )

Answer (score 2):

I arrived here because I simply hadn't installed the program that gives the `ssh-keygen` command.

[This](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/ssh-keygen-command-not-found/) resource lists how to do that for just about any system:

- macOS:    `brew install openssh`
- Debian:   `apt-get install openssh-client`
- Ubuntu:   `apt-get install openssh-client`
- Alpine:   `apk add openssh`
- Arch Linux:   `pacman -S openssh`
- Kali Linux:   `apt-get install openssh-client`
- CentOS:   `yum install openssh`
- Fedora:   `dnf install openssh`
- Raspbian: `apt-get install openssh-client`
- Docker:   `docker run cmd.cat/ssh-keygen ssh-keygen`

I was using Ubuntu so I ran `apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-client` and then the `ssh-keygen` command worked as expected.